# How to webscrape and click a button based on user input

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm making a python file that should interact with this website. I want it to click a button (Month name) based on what month the user inputs. The webscraping is being done by selenium chromedriver. What python line should I use?

[Here is the website page with button and the element inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFkG7.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your 'python file'?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows no efforts from the OP at all, simply asking for ready-made solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple way's for doing this. Here's the easiest one that I could think of:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.yourwebsitehere.com')

month = input("Type Month, For e.g: jan for January \n>> ")

try:
    month_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(" //div[text()=month.upper]")
    month_elem.click()
    
except:
    print("Element Not Found!")
```

Let's break down the code.

Don't worry about the first few lines as they are just an example. What you should focus on is this line

```
month_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(" //div[text()=month.upper]")
month_elem.click()
```

This search for certain text in and click's on it. Here the text it searches for is "month" which is user input.

Note: Here the user should input short forms for months. For eg:

- **jan** for January
- **mar** for march
- **dec** for December

month.upper is also important as those texts are also in uppercase.

This is not the most relevant way, but this should work